# What is the meaning of the "a" character in Chrome's menu icon

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm using both regular Chrome Dev and Chrome Canary. A few weeks ago, the menu icon in Canary got a nice little "a" attached to it.

Anybody know what this is?

[image: Screenshot illustrating the strange "a"]

Comment: Comes only on Chrome dev, btw

Answer (score 2):

[This opens the Ash Desktop](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/9peJTNsc2iw/fjNCFtZPAE4J) (whatever that is).

Comment: Thats the desktop environment chromebooks use. I do recall there's some sort of launcher for webapps in canary as well, so I guess you will be able to use ash on windows or linux in the future.

Comment: How? It's just there within the regular icon to open the menu!? There's nothing else to click.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right, this isn't an option in the menu, it's a little "a" on the icon. There is nothing about Ash Desktop in the menu. Nor would that explain why they would put an a on it.

Comment: is there any way to get rid of it? Chrome is a big enough pig already without trying to emulate a whole OS in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It provides [chrome OS experience](https://plus.google.com/100132233764003563318/posts/4iqFg4aTcua) on Windows using [Ash functionality](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/02/10/test-googles-chrome-os-on-windows/).
Though the Ash link is not available under menu in current latest canary builds, as mentioned on the second link.